# Set request header in Protractor

Tags: protractor

Is it possible to set request headers in Protractor?

In the following post (2014), Protractor confirmed that currently they don't have any way to do this (as protractor was not designed to interact with under-the-hood things.
[here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/740)

Has anyone found out a way how to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I implemented a simple proxy to inject headers in the requests. I published it on npm repository. You can find it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/headers-injection-proxy

Very easy to use:

```
header-injection-proxy -p 3000 -t "https://www.google.com" -h "headers.json"
```

At that point you just send the requests to the proxy instead of the real server

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external library like `request`. For me it worked as a charm with Protractor:

https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers

EDIT:
Here you have an example of implementation. It uses [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';
import {put} from 'request-promise';
import {ADMIN_URL} from '../data/definitions/urls';

export class CreateUser {
    public setRoles(username: string, roles: string[]) {
        return this.getUserId(username).then((userId) => {
            const data = {
                url: `${ADMIN_URL}/user/${userId}/role`,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: browser.params.token
                },
                body: roles,
                json: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            };

            return put(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example? how are the headers added ? do you add it within the baseURL property in protractor.conf file ?